# How do i add the wsgi_module to the apache2.conf file?

Tags: apache2

I am running a 32bit version of apache/ubuntu.
I need to edit the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file.

I can't seem to find where the module will fit or load.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you installed it by running `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi`.

`a2enmod` is the command to enable apache modules, so you have to run:

```
sudo a2enmod wsgi
```

If don't know the module name just run `sudo a2enmod` and it will show you which modules are enabled and which modules can be enable.